# System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, ioexception, system.net.webexception

I am trying to access a 3rd party API using "Basic" encoding but I am getting an exception with WebClient.DownloadData()

Here is the code

**Controller**

```
public string Get()
{
    return new MyModel().GetAll();
}
```

**Model**

```
public string GetAll()
{
    string auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password);
    string enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(auth));
    client.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("{0} {1}","Basic", enc);
    string response = Encoding.Default.GetString(client.DownloadData(url)); // fails here (please see screenshot)
}
```

[image]

Similar questions on internet/stackoverflow say the solution is to check the `SecurityProtocol`

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
//I added 'SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3' but it didn't help. I am still getting the same error.
```

I added `SecurityProtocol` in `Controller` as well as in `Global.asax.cs` but no luck.

I am using Windows 11 for calling the API

.NET Framework of project is 4.6.1

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Get a Wireshark trace and see what the Client Hello and Server Hello look like, is there a matching TLS version and cipher suite? Do not set the `SecurityProtocol` manually, rely on the operating system. Which exact version and build number of Windows and .NET do you have?

Comment: @Charlieface Windows 11 
.NET Framework of project is 4.6.1

Comment: But what is the installed version of .NET? The target of the project is irrelevant as long as it's .NET Framework 4.* it's what you got installed. What about the server, what is that running?

Comment: @Charlieface .NET Framework 4.6.1 or a later update is already installed

Comment: What version of Windows is installed on the server? What versions of TLS and ciphers are enabled (download and use the IIS Crypto tool to see)

Comment: I am unsure of the server details and other details you mentioned. I will have to check that.

Comment: According to [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls): _To ensure .NET Framework applications remain secure, the TLS version should not be hardcoded. ..For TLS 1.2, target .NET Framework 4.7 or later versions on your apps, and target .NET Framework 4.7.1 or later versions on your WCF apps. For TLS 1.3, target .NET Framework 4.8 or later._ Also see: [How to: Configure network tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing)

Comment: TLS 1.1 is obsolete and should ber removed from following : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3; Net Framework 4.6.1 may not implement the encryption mode in certificate and will fail.  It is best that you use Net 4.7 or later where the TLS is performed in the OS instead of in Net.  All encryption modes are supported in Win 11, while not all modes will work in Net 4.6.1.